# server side function is invoked by client side irrespective of TRUE or FALSE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

within a gridview, i have a template column, which has a linkButtton column within it.
when the linkButton column is clicked, it triggers the client side, which if TRUE should call the server side event.
but somehow, the server side event is been invoked in both cases - TRUE or FALSE.
please let me know, if i'm missing on something......

markup code goes as --

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disable/Enable" ItemStyle-Width="10%"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"#
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ableDisableLaborCode" CommandName="linkButtonClick" CommandArgument='#%# Eval("coLaborCodeID") %#'##/asp:LinkButton#
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is where the client side event is registered

```
Private Sub gridVwCoLaborCodes_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As     System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gridVwCoLaborCodes.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        Dim _lnk As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ableDisableLaborCode"), LinkButton)
        Dim _drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
        _lnk.Text = If(CBoolBit(_drv(Fields.NAME_FIELD_IS_ENABLED_FLAG)), "Disable", "Enable")
        _lnk.OnClientClick = String.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you want to deactivate this labor code ?');")
    End If
End Sub
```

following is the code for the server side event --

```
Private Sub gridVwCoLaborCodes_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gridVwCoLaborCodes.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "linkButtonClick" Then
        CoLaborCodeId = CIntNull(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

thanks to all viewed and helped.

Comment: does the script on displays a confirmation box and based on user's response does what?

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign the javascript event in a different way:

```
Private Sub gridVwCoLaborCodes_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gridVwCoLaborCodes.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        Dim _lnk As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ableDisableLaborCode"), LinkButton)
        Dim _drv As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
        _lnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to deactivate this labor code ?');")
        lnk.Text = If(CBoolBit(_drv(Fields.NAME_FIELD_IS_ENABLED_FLAG)), "Disable", "Enable")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Razvan -- i'll surely try that and update u of the success or failure.